# LINQ to Entities, how to return all records from the Parent table?

Tags: linq-to-entities, left-join

I am unable to select all the records from the parent table using Linq to Entities.

This is a simple DB design (image below):

<strike>[Image Link](http://www.thinkboard.com/myimages/tablerelation.jpg)</strike> (Dead Link)

This is the exact output I want using Linq to Entities or Linq to SQL (image below):

<strike>[Image Link](http://www.thinkboard.com/myimages/sqlresults.jpg)</strike> (Dead Link)

When I use Linq to Entities or Linq To Sql, I can only get the records from the child table that has a foreign key relation. I am not able to get the null values as shown above.

I want to have the null values show just like when you use `left outer join`.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Your sample output seems to be missing from your question...

Answer (score 1):

```
from entity in MyContext.EntityType.Include("ChildEntitiesNavigationPropertyName")
select entity;
```

This returns all instances of EntityType, plus ChildEntitiesNavigationPropertyName when/if it exists. For tabular form use an anonymous type:

```
from entity in MyContext.EntityType.Include("ChildEntitiesNavigationPropertyName")
select new {ParentProperty = entity.ParentProperty, 
            ChildProperty  = entity.ChildEntitiesNavigationPropertyName.ChildProperty};
```

For a 1..* property:

```
from entity in MyContext.EntityType.Include("ChildEntitiesNavigationPropertyName")
from child in entity.ChildEntitiesNavigationPropertyName.DefaultIfEmpty()
select new {ParentProperty = entity.ParentProperty, 
            ChildProperty  = child.ChildProperty};
```

Comment: When I do example it just says childproperty is not defined.  All though works From Child in entity.ChildEntitiesNavigationPropertyName, which does not give me the Null records I want.

Comment: You must be using a 1..* property then. In that case, use group by to join. I'll update the example.

Comment: By the way are you seeing my images in the question?  The images show up when I edit the question but cannot see them when view the question.

Comment: No. I'm guessing, because I can't see them.

Comment: Ok put links to the images, not sure why the images are not showing.  
Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Craig created another question more specific.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/544378/linq-to-entities-how-to-return-all-records-from-parent

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you can select from employees and then do a left join in LINQ, something like this (I don't have VS on this machine):

```
var results = from e in dbContext.Employees join s in dbContext.Sales on e.EmployeeID equals s.EmployeeID select new { e, s };
```

You may want to select the columns you just want.  Hope it gives you the results you want.

Comment: If there is no answer by the time I get into work tomorrow, I'll work on it.  But instead of trying to work from the Sales up to the Employees, you need to join Employees with Sales.

Comment: The lead table is Employee, just can't beleive that a simple query is to difficult.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: I completely forgot!  Let me have a look and see now.