# Linq to Entities How to return all records from Parent?

Tags: linq-to-entities, left-join

### Employee table

Employee_ID int
Employee_Name   varchar(50)

### Sales table:

Sales_ID             int
Employee_ID int
Sale_Amount money

### Standard SQL select

Select
     *
From 
    Employee emp
    left outer join
    Sales s
    on
    s.Employee_ID = emp.Employee_ID

### Standard SQL Results (The exact results I want using Linq to Entites)

1        Emp1   1   1   150.00
1   Emp1    2   1   500.00
2   Emp2    3   2   250.00
3   Emp3    NULL    NULL    NULL
4   Emp4    NULL    NULL    NULL
5   Emp5    4   5   700.00

### Now to tackle Linq To Entities

```
            Dim query = From emp In entiites.Employee _
                    From sales In emp.Sales _
                    Select _
                        emp, _
                        sales
```

### Linq To Entities Result (Where is Employee_ID 3 and 4)

1: Emp1: 150.0000
1: Emp1: 500.0000
2: Emp2: 250.0000
5: Emp5: 700.0000

### Try it with Linq to Entities with a left outer join:

```
            Dim query = From emp In entiites.Employee _
                    Group Join sales In entiites.Sales _
                    On emp.Employee_ID Equals sales.Employee.Employee_ID _
                    Into sales_grp = Group _
                    From Sel_SalesGrp In sales_grp.DefaultIfEmpty() _
                    Select _
                        emp, _
                        Sel_SalesGrp
```

**Then I get this error using DefaultIfEmpty:**

LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[m12Model.Sales] DefaultIfEmpty[Sales](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[m12Model.Sales])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

### Linq to Entites: does not support DefaultIfEmpty().

Answer (score 2):

You need to perform a left join by using the "Into" and "DefaultIfEmpty()" keywords:

```
Dim query = From emp In entities.Employee _
        Join sal In entities.Sales On emp.Employee_ID Equals sal.Employee_ID Into LeftJoinSal _
        From ljs In LeftJoinSal.DefaultIfEmpty() _
        Select _
            emp, _
            ljs
```

This site shows another simple example: [GeeksWithBlogs](https://web.archive.org/web/20200924115132/http://geekswithblogs.net/AzamSharp/archive/2008/04/07/121103.aspx).  Though it is in C#.

The key is that you need to join into a new name to prevent it from filtering the results from your first table (which hides the rows that don't join), then select from that using the DefaultIfEmpty() function, which provides a default (null) value in the cases where there is no join.

Comment: DefaultIfEmpty() is not supported in Linq to Entities

Comment: The link is (effectively) broken. It redirects to *[Geekswithblogs.net, the End of an Era](http://julian.farm/geekswithblogs/?url=/mtreadwell/archive/2004/06/06/6123.aspx)*.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
Dim query = From emp In entiites.Employee Join sales In In entiites.Sales _
    On emp.Employee_ID Equals sales.Employee_ID select new { emp, sales }
```

Instead of "select new { emp, sales }" you can select the columns you want.  That should be a standard left join using LINQ.

Comment: Thanks achinda99,
Still only able to get the Employee records that have a maching sales record.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have found a solution by now, but I have a suggestion, using a different approach than joins:

```
    Dim db As New TestEntities
    Dim EmptySale As Decimal? = Nothing
    Dim Q = (From emp In db.Employee From sale In emp.Sale _
             Select emp.Name, amount =sale.SaleAmount).ToList
    Dim Q2 = (From emp In db.Employee Where Not emp.Sale.Any _
             Select emp.Name, amount = EmptySale)
    Dim Q3 = From emp In Q.Union(Q2) Order By emp.Name, emp.amount

    For Each e In Q3
        Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", e.Name, e.amount)
    Next
```

The result of this is:

```
Emp1 150,00
Emp1 500,00
Emp2 250,00
Emp3
Emp4
Emp5 750,00
```

I hope this can help you